# Dynamic Array Of Char to Store Image from a Binary File: C

Tags: c, arrays, image, dynamic, binary

I am learning C programming and have a question for allocating dynamic memory to array.

I am trying to read a binary file (it contains ascii art, which is a image). The first two lines contain width(100) and height(48) respectively. Followed by ascii art.

```
void readDimension(FILE *inFile, int *width, int *height)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", width);
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", height);
        }
    }
}

unsigned char *foo(char *filename, int *width, int *height)
{
    // Inside Foo I must create dynamic array of char to store image data
    // Recommendation is to used fread()
    // Also account for the carriage return at the end of file

    **I am stuck, in how to allocate array dynamically and read data into the same**
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *inFile;
    int width, height;



    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Please specify a file name.\n");
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        inFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (inFile != NULL)
        {
            readDimension(inFile, &width, &height);
            foo(argv[1], &width, &height);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: File Not Found %s", argv[1]);
        }   
    }

    printf("Width: %d\n", width);
    printf("Height: %d\n", height);
}
```

Comment: Try reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation and ask again if you have more specific questions.

Comment: @Mabus So will i be creating an empty array `unsigned char array[]` and then applying the `malloc` on it?

Comment: 1) Declaration such `unsinged char *c_art;` in `main` and  The file already opened in main and `foo` not needs pointer to `width` and `height`, change API call `c_art=foo(inFile, width, height);`,  2)in `foo` : `unsigned char *ret = malloc(width * height); fread(ret, 1, width*height, inFile); return ret;`,

Comment: No. You should store the result of malloc in a pointer variable. For example `char * myArray = malloc(sizeNeeded);`. Then, you need to check that the allocation succeeded (myArray is not NULL). Next you can fill the contents of myArray as if it is a real array. When you don't need myArray anymore, you can free the memory using free over any pointer that points to the begining of myArray (for example myArray itself).

Comment: You have probably misunderstood `malloc` or arrays: an array is a variable in your programme, and may not be empty. It may be accessed by name or (less safely) by a pointer which has been set to one of its elements. This is less safe as the pointer does not know the number of elements, which you must track by hand. `malloc` returns a pointer to memory with which you may in principle do anything, though in practice what you usually do is use it as a pointer to a single object or a series of objects like an array. You need to allocate as many bytes as you need, and access them with a pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It is the requirement to have a function `unsigned char *foo(char *filename, int *width, int *height)`. Do you still think your answer is still valid? Should I change the assignment to `c_art = foo(argh[1], &width, &height)`

Comment: @user3337714 Interface is good anyhow, but you need that you do not open the file in double.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So how would I use `fread()` in the `foo` function. Since `fread()` requires `FILE` object, but the requirement of the code only accepts the `filename` argument in the `foo` function. Do I have to close in `main` and open again the file again in `foo`

Comment: change to file open and call `readDimension` in `foo`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY cannot do that, since the dimensions are supposed to be passed to the `foo` function and not calculated within the function.

Comment: you can do it. at `main` : `unsinged char *c_art=foo(argv[1], &width, &height);`, at `foo` : `FILE *inFile=fopen(filename, "rb");   readDimension(inFile, width, height);  unsigned char *ret = malloc(*width * *height); fread(ret, 1, *width * *height, inFile); fclose(inFile); return ret;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79714/discussion-between-user3337714-and-bluepixy).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY When I am trying to print `art`, I am getting the output as `NULL`?.